# Unable to import Module in Lambda

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have a simple exports.js file and I have zipped the folder and upload it to Lambda but on run time it gives an error:

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'exports'",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": 
[
"Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)",
"Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)",
"Module.require (module.js:364:17)",
"require (module.js:380:17)"
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your folder structure and possibly where you're trying to `require` the "exports" module?

Comment: If you're still facing the issue maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43105773/4455570
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

1.Name the file exports.js

2.Name the handler, within the file, exports.handler

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) 
{
    var YourSkill = new YourSkill();
    YourSkill.execute(event, context);
}
```

3.Set the handler in the lambda config to exports.handler

4.Zip up only the contents of the folder, if you zip the folder as well it will not find your file.

5.Rename the zip file exports.zip

Answer (score 0):

Include a directory called `node_modules` in your directory.
Zip the your index.js + the `node_modules` directory and upload.